# How do you regain your privacy?

Tags: networking, vpn, privacy

my sister know my ip, default gateway, dhcp server, dns and more. She has a degree in computer science and i think this is how she monitor my internet traffic Ive tryed ip and mac address and didnt work. Do I need to change the info she have or Is a vpn good enough to gain privacy?

Comment: None of those items are private. Why are you so worried about someone knowing them? Changing your computer, router and modem will not change any of those.

Comment: If you have a shared IP, you can turn of your modem for a few hours and turn it on to get a new IP. The rest of the settings can be configured. No need to buy new hardware. Then again, people can't do much with this info anyway.

Comment: thank you. ive try changing my ip and it did work. (also i clarified my question) what would you recommend?

Comment: Are you living in the same house as your sister?  Is she using the same internet router that you are?  Or did she at one time?  Most internet routers allow you to send usage reports to an email address.  If she turned that on, then your router could be reporting to her what you're doing.  Do a factory reset on the router to take care of that if you don't know the admin password.  If this isn't actually your sister, but your parents checking up on you, then they'll figure out something changed and come looking for you to ask why.

Comment: lol. no we dont live together and she doesnt have physical access to my computer.

Comment: If your sister has a CS degree, forget it.  She owns you.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

**Replacing all your equipment will just be a waste of money** Also this can't really be used to harm you in a significant way. Your ip address can be used for some childish behavior but nothing more than harmless pranks.

But as stated in one of the comment above, if you have a shared IP, just turn of your modem for a few hours or call your isp and ask them to give you a new ip, depending on your provider they may help you.

Also getting a vpn now won't help you regain privisie if you already did something you want to hide, then the damage has already been done. However getting a good vpn is always a good idea for the future.

**It's not bulletproof but makes the barrier of entry higher so you wont be there/the first target.**

## Edit

If your sister has a computer science degree things get a lot more complicated. Your personal network information still is not the source of your problems. Not to scare you but she can be using multiple exploits at this point or just straight up have a back door in your computer.

Because i don't know what she did, follow the following steps. They may seem a bit extreme but as i don't have access to your network(I'm a stranger on the internet so let's keep it that way) i can only make assumptions.

Change your passwords on a computer she doesn't know about (a friends house) and never connect any of your current devices to his netwerk for now. Do this for all of your accounts, especially your email account (Because of password recovery) DO NOT USE THE SAME PASSWORD MORE THEN ONCE, and never use a password that means something to you.

First off all, reset or straight up reinstall your firmware on both your router and modem and for the love of god change the default manufacturers password. Do the same for all devices connected to the internet because they can be a breeding pool for exploits.

Now for your computer your best bet is a complete reinstallation of windows or linux and install a virus scanner and anti malware software. From this point onwards, never accept or open anything she sends. No links to a cute picture or a mp3 file you just have to listen to.

Get your self a VPN and put the encryption on the max, and never trust anybody ever again a special family.

Comment: thank you. ive try changing my ip and it did work. (also i clarified my question) what would you recommend?

Comment: Np, i updated my answer for you, using the clarified question.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, not a lot of point in changing your external IP address, its fairly public information (and the next time you send her an email she will probably be able to deduce it from the headers anyway, or visit a website she controls or....)

If you are using a home router, your default gateway, DNS server etc are typically the IP address of the gateway, so its also no big deal.

The thing is that she should not be able to snoop on you using these things - if you are sure she is doing so, she has planted some kind of software on your router - or more likely PC - which is phoning home.  Until you find and get rid of this software, she controls your system, and possibly your network.

IF SHE HAS COMPROMISED YOUR ROUTER, then yes, you should replace it - but with one of a different brand.  (You may be able to flash different firmware to it).   That said, if she is good enough to compromise your router, chances are she will find another way in to your systems, so this may not help much long term.   Using a VPN will also protect you from this attack vector.

IF SHE HAS COMPROMISED YOUR COMPUTER, you may be able to clean up with anti-malware or antivirus software, but as it may be an "advanced persistent attack", you may be better off reinstalling your system from scratch.   You may also want to consider a different OS.

If you are genuinely concerned long term, you should replace your current router with a reasonably powerful one which supports DD-WRT or equivalent, and then learn about wireshark, TCPDump and the like - and monitor your outbound packets.  Unfortunately this is not trivial.

Also, because it is a family member doing this, bear in mind that she has/is most likely heavily using social engineering.  This is one of the most effective means of hacking - so its important to become wise to what she is doing.   (And, if you can't trust her, change passwords to all your important accounts - especially your email accounts - AND ALSO SECURITY QUESTIONS TO SOMETHING SHE DOES NOT KNOW)